# Yii2 custom sql query in gridview

Tags: php, sql, gridview, yii, yii2

I'm quite new to Yii2.
I'm using advanced structure

I need to show a custom sql result in a view without using a model because I would like to display a sql view.

index.php

```
<?= GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'COD_RISORSA',
            [
                'label' =>"Nome",
                'attribute' => 'NOME',
                'value'=>function($data){
                    return $data["NOME"];
                }
            ],
            'COGNOME',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
   ]); ?>
```

VRisorseController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $totalCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_risorse')->queryScalar();

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM v_risorse',
        'totalCount' => $totalCount,
        'sort' =>false,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

At the following Url:
http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=vrisorse%2Findex

I have the error:

> Not Supported – yii\base\NotSupportedException Message format 'number'
>   is only supported for integer values. You have to install PHP intl
>   extension to use this feature.
>   1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\i18n\MessageFormatter.php

I tried to comment all the columns in gridview, and the error seems to be related to `$dataProvider` variable

`'COD_RISORSA','NOME', 'COGNOME'` are columns of the select.

Comment: The error seems related to intl feature, post your config please.

Comment: in your `php.ini` uncomment `extension=php_intl.dll` and restart webserver

Answer (score 4):

You need to install PHP intl extension.i had the same error

given below is my working code 
in controller

```
$count      =   Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
                    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM screen_ticket_booking_history WHERE status=:status
                    ', [':status' => 0])->queryScalar();

                    $sql =  "SELECT A1.booking_id As Booking_id,
                                A1.booking_date As Booking_date,
                                A2.movie_name As Movie,
                                A3.theatre_name As Theatre,
                                A1.amount As Amount

                                FROM 
                                screen_ticket_booking_history A1

                                LEFT OUTER JOIN movies A2 ON A1.movie_id=A2.id
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN theatres A3 ON A1.theatre_id=A3.id
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN users_backend A4 ON A3.users_backend_id=A4.id

                                WHERE A1.booking_date = '{$day}'
                                AND   A1.movie_id='{$movies->id}'";


                    //~ $models = $dataProvider->getModels(); //print_r($models);die();
                    if( $userid != '1')
                    { 
                        $sql .= " AND A3.users_backend_id = '{$userid}' ";
                    }

                    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
                    'sql' => $sql,
                    'totalCount' => $count,
                    ]);
                    return $this->render('index',
                    [   'model'             => $model,
                        'dataProvider'      => $dataProvider,
                    ]);
                }
```

and below is my view

```
<?= GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'columns' => [
           ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

           'Booking_id',
           'Booking_date',
           'Movie',
           'Theatre',
           'Amount',
           //~ ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
       ],
   ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem，It is easy to solve.You need assign the DB as bellow:

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $totalCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_risorse')->queryScalar();

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        **'db' => Yii::$app->db,**
        'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM v_risorse',
        'totalCount' => $totalCount,
        'sort' =>false,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers#sql-data-provider

Example:

**Create $dataProvider (controller):**

```
public function actionIndex($src, $disposition, $start, $finish)
    {
                $count = $connection->createCommand("
                select COUNT(*)
                from cdr 
                where (Length(dst) > 6) 
                and (start between :start and :finish)  
                and (lastapp=\"Dial\") 
                and src in (:src)
                and disposition in ('ANSWERED', 'FAILED', 'BUSY', 'NO ANSWER')")
                ->bindValue(':src', $params['src'])
                ->bindValue(':start', $params['start'])
                ->bindValue(':finish', $params['finish'])->queryScalar();

                $sql = "select src, dst,
                Case Disposition
                when 'ANSWERED' then 'Отвечено'
                when 'FAILED' then 'Ошибка'
                when 'BUSY' then 'Занято'
                when 'NO ANSWER' then 'Не дозвонились'    
                else 'ИТОГ'    
                End as status,
                Start,
                Round(billsec/60, 2) as Billing,
                uniqueid
                from cdr 
                where (Length(dst) > 6) 
                and (start between :start and :finish)  
                and (lastapp=\"Dial\") 
                and src in (:src)
                and disposition in ('ANSWERED', 'FAILED', 'BUSY', 'NO ANSWER')";

                $boundParams = [
                   ':src' => $params['src'],
                   ':start' => $params['start'],
                   ':finish' => $params['finish'],
                ];

        //   Provider
        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $sql,
            'params' => $boundParams,
            'totalCount' => $count,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 150,
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => [
                    'src',
                    'dst',
                    'Start',
                    'Billing',
                    'uniqueid',
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        return $this->render('index', [
            'params' => $params,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'count' => $count,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Create GridView (view):**

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'label' => 'От кого',
            'attribute' => 'src',
//            'format' => ['decimal', 2],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Кому',
            'attribute' => 'dst',
//            'format' => ['decimal', 2],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Начало',
            'attribute' => 'Start',
//            'format' => ['decimal', 2],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Длительность (сек)',
            'attribute' => 'Billing',
//            'format' => ['decimal', 2],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'UUID',
            'attribute' => 'uniqueid',
//            'format' => ['decimal', 2],
        ],
        //~ ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment

> extension=php_mysql.dll

and

> extension=php_mysqli.dll

in your php.ini, let me know if works

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to the basic question is:

```
    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => '<your query/>',
    ]);
    echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Flesh it out as complex as you like using SqlDataProvider and GridView params.