# how to use relation table when using sqldataprovider

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

please help I dont know how to get relation table when using sqldataprovider. Anyone understand how to use relation model?

```
$model = new Finalresult();
$searchModel = new FinalresultSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
   'sql' => 'SELECT finalresult.bib,
            finalresult.series_id,
            finalresult.category_id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT finalresult.point ORDER BY series.serie_seri_no DESC) AS seriPoint 
            FROM finalresult, series GROUP BY finalresult.bib',
    'key' => 'bib',
]);
```

I'm trying to get relation table:

```
'attribute'=>'category_id', 
'width'=>'300px',
'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) { 
     return $model->category->category_name;
},
```

then getting trying to non-object

Comment: show `FinalResult` model. it's a `gridview` or `detailView`?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945259/yii2-custom-sql-query-in-gridview

Answer (score 2):

You can't use relations with `SqlDataProvider`, because each single result will be presented as array, for example:

```
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Some name',
    'category_id' => 1,
],
```

For example, you can access `category_id` as `$model['category_id'].

`SqlDataProvider` is for very very complex queries, your query can easily be written as `ActiveQuery` and you can use `ActiveDataProvider` and get all advantages of that (relations, etc.).

You can find category by id, but it will be lazily loaded that means amount of queries is multiplied by number of rows.

With `ActiveDataProvider` and relations you can use eager loading and reduce amount of queries. Read more in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading).

Answer (score 0):

[Grid Columns example in documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-columns)

try to change "value" to

```
'value'=> function($data) { 
     return $data['category']['category_name'];
}
```